# Constant json inferred to have 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift

I am using below code for json parsing but compiler is complaining warning "**Constant json inferred to have 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected**". How would I resolve warning? My json response may be json Array or Dictionary. How to achieve it in common way?

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: nil)
if let j = json as? Array<AnyObject> {
    //this is an array
} else if let j = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    //this is a dict
}
```

Comment: json can json array or json dictionary.How would you considering it will be all time dictionary?

Comment: ok so i looked into it, looks like JSON "[1, 2, 3]" is considered valid, but i would still advise to use "{array : [1, 2, 3]}".

Comment: "[]" => it's a valid json and Array how to catch that using your code?

Comment: I don't have access in backend and json is still valid

Comment: yup Perfect! Accepted Answer